# Safari list of closed sessions feature

Tags: safari

I don't use Safari that often but I remember this really nice feature where you could scroll through a list of previously closed sessions. I think it was located on the "Top Sites" page that Safari features. Now I can't find it, so I'm guessing either it was erased in an update or moved somewhere. Is there a way to access this list of closed sessions?

Comment: What version of Safari do you have?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Safari 6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

It is still there and it looks like this

[image]

Under the History Tab - Show Top Sites

in my Safari 6.0.5

Comment: No it's different from history, because I remember when my history was deleted I found that all my closed sessions could be scrolled through and organized by date.